# What's the difference between "java.io.IOException: Connection timed out" and "SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"

Tags: java, network-programming

If I set a socket SoTimeout, and read from it. when read time exceed the timeout limit, I'll get an "SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out".
and here is the stack in my case:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:277)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:527)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:462)
```

---

but here I encountered "IOExcetion: Connection timed out", i don't know how it happened. 
Stacks:

```
java.io.IOException: Connection timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:128)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:277)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:527)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:462)
```

Can someone tell me what's the differences between the two exceptions, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A connection timeout means you attempted to connect to the remote IP/port pair and failed to do so: it did not answer at all. Another possible error at that stage would be connection refused, in which this pair is available but rejected your connection attempt. Both of these errors appear on the initial setup of a socket. Note that these errors only occur with TCP, since a TCP connection requires the establishment of a session.

When you have a socket read timeout, it means you *are* connected, but failed to read data in time. Timeouts on sockets are configurable. You may also get a connection reset error, which means you did connect successfully, but the other end decided that after all you're not worth it :p

Comment: thx fge. But I think the stack is **reading** not **connecting** in the Connection timeout case

Comment: What "stack"? No, connection timeout happens when you _attempt_ to connect but fail. Do you know how TCP works?

Comment: i mean stack traces, fge :) the two stacks show Exception thrown while reading sth not connecting

Comment: I don't know jstack, sorry. But you'll notice right below your filedispatcher line that there is a `SocketDispatcher`.

Comment: that's a native read method, i don't know how it works :( I want to know how to change the timeout configuration to avoid this.

Comment: ok. i'm gonna find more info about this native method. thx again :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer:

In one case (`Connection timed out`) your application cannot connect to the server in a timely manner. In the other case (`Read timed out`) the connection can be established but during read the connection times out.

Comment: THX Plonus. But I think the stacks show that it's sth wrong with the reading in the `Connection timed out`case

Answer (score 0):

'Connection timed out' after the connect phase means that something has gone seriously wrong with the connection and it must be closed. 'Read timeout' just means that no data arrived within the specified receive timeout period: it isn't fatal.